# Tikz picture (arc) cant be positioned

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynmp, feynmp-auto

I am trying to put an arc done with Tikz (representing a current) with a Feynman Diagram (done with feynmp), but even if a try changing the coordinates of the Tikz picture it wont change.

My code is the follwing:

```
    \documentclass[margin=25 mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{feynmp-auto}
    \usepackage{tikz}  % pras correntes
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
  

    %%_________________________________________ feynman diagram


    \newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
        \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
            expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
            label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
            enddef;}
        \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
    
    %%_________________________________________ 

    \begin{fmffile}{dgs}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
        \fmfleft{i1,i2}
        \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i1}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \marrow{ea}{ up }{top}{$P_A$}{i2,v2}
        \marrow{eb}{down}{bot}{$P_C$}{v2,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \marrow{ma}{down}{bot}{$P_B$}{i1,v1}
        \marrow{mb}{ up }{top}{$P_D$}{v1,o1}
        \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}

    %%_________________________________________end of feynman diagram

    %%%_________________________________________ tikz pictures: 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, ->] (0,0)  arc[radius = 20mm, start angle= 150, end angle= 25];
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, ->] (0,0)  arc[radius = 20mm, start angle= 210, end angle= 335];
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

P.s.: In order to make the diagram appear on the pdf you have to compile the metapost auxiliar file with metapost compilation.

I would like the arcs to be above and below the diagram.

Comment: please make your code compilable.

Comment: Done. Thanks for warning me.

Comment: If feynmp is NOT based on TikZ, you can put it inside a TikZ node.  If it is, you can still put it into a savebox and put the savebox inside a node.

Answer (score 5):

The coordinates inside a `tikzpicture` are not relative to the page or text block, only the other coordinates inside the same `tikzpicture`. The  bounding box of the diagram is cropped to the contents of the diagram, and afterwards it is placed on the page by TeX the same way as for example an image, or a letter, is placed on the page. Hence, `\tikz\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);` looks exactly the same as `\tikz\draw (10,10) -- (11,10);` because both are `tikzpicture`s consisting of a single horizontal arrow of length 1. (`\tikz` is a shortform for the `tikzpicture` environment.)

So what you have are three separate boxes placed on the page, one after the other. One box for the Feynman diagram, one for each of the arcs. Because of how the `standalone` class works, they are placed next to each other. If this was in an `article` class for example, they would be placed on top of each other, because there is a paragraph break (an empty line) between each separate diagram. You can get the same thing in `standalone` if you add the `varwidth` option to the class

One quick fix for this specific case could therefore be to place all three diagrams in a `center environment`, first the top arc made by TikZ, then the Feynman-diagram, then the second arc. This works because the Feynman diagram is symmetric about the vertical.

It might be better to do as John Kormylo suggested in a comment though, because then you can put everything in the same `tikzpicture`, and position the arcs relative to other diagram elements. Or possibly use the `tikz-feynman` package to draw the diagram.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[border=25mm, varwidth=true]{standalone} % <-- added varwidth=true

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{feynmp-auto}
    \usepackage{tikz}  % pras correntes
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
        \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
            expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
            label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
            enddef;}
        \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
    
    \begin{document}
  
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, ->] (0,0)  arc[radius = 20mm, start angle= 150, end angle= 25];
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{fmffile}{dgs}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
        \fmfleft{i1,i2}
        \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i1}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \marrow{ea}{ up }{top}{$P_A$}{i2,v2}
        \marrow{eb}{down}{bot}{$P_C$}{v2,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \marrow{ma}{down}{bot}{$P_B$}{i1,v1}
        \marrow{mb}{ up }{top}{$P_D$}{v1,o1}
        \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}

    %%_________________________________________end of feynman diagram

    %%%_________________________________________ tikz pictures: 


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, ->] (0,0)  arc[radius = 20mm, start angle= 210, end angle= 335];
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved the problem.